# Dialog Fragment collapsing when opened

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an app based on [trivial drive v2](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/tree/master/TrivialDrive_v2) that loads the following view in its main activity:

**layout/activity_wallpaper.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@id/screen_main">

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <!--Include loading screen-->
        <include layout="@layout/loading_indicator"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

rendered as:

[image]

Some of the list items are purchasable and start a new activity when tapped on, which in turn, creates a dialog fragment from the layout:

**layout/acquire_fragment.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/acquire_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/list_bg_color">

    <include layout="@layout/loading_indicator" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/primary_color"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        style="@style/ToolbarStyle"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/error_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/single_padding"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

rendered as:

[image]

Each entry in the dialog fragment is composed of two rows (header, entry):

**layout/sku_details_row_header.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    style="@style/CardViewStyle"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/sku_details_row_header_height"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/row_header_bg_color">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/double_padding"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/double_padding"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sku_details_row_text_size"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

rendered as:

[image]

and **layout/sku_details_row.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    style="@style/CardViewStyle"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/sku_details_row_height"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/row_bg_color">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="@dimen/sku_details_row_padding">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sku_details_row_text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/price"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/single_padding"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/single_padding"
                android:textColor="@color/ascent_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sku_details_row_text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/single_padding">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sku_icon"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/single_padding"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/single_padding"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sku_details_row_description_text_size"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/state_button"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/single_padding"
            android:contentDescription="@string/button_buy"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

rendered as:

[image]

Upon running the app, the sku entry (header and row) collapse into the center of
the screen:

[image]

whereas, in the sample app they it doesn't (sku row takes up whole screen):

[image]

The only difference in terms of layout between the apps is the activity view. Sample activity view:

**TrivialDrivev2/layout/activity_game.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/loading_indicator"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/screen_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/title_margin"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_title_image"
            android:src="@drawable/title"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/free_or_premium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/image_margin"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc_free_vs_premium_indicator"
            android:src="@drawable/free"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/gas_gauge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/image_margin"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc_gas_gauge_indicator"
            android:src="@drawable/gas4"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@id/button_drive"
                style="@style/DriveButtonStyle"
                android:text="@string/button_drive"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@id/button_purchase"
                style="@style/ButtonStyle"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/double_padding"
                android:text="@string/button_purchase"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

and is rendered as:

[image]

The code that renders both sku entries is the same:

**AcquireFragment.java:**

```
// If we successfully got SKUs, add a header in front of the row
@StringRes int stringRes = SkuType.INAPP.equals(billingType)
        ? R.string.header_inapp : R.string.header_subscriptions;
inList.add(new SkuRowData(getString(stringRes)));
// Then fill all the other rows
for (SkuDetails details : skuDetailsList) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Adding sku: " + details);
    inList.add(new SkuRowData(details, SkusAdapter.TYPE_NORMAL,
            billingType));
}

if (inList.size() == 0) {
    displayAnErrorIfNeeded();
} else {
    if (mRecyclerView.getAdapter() == null) {
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        Resources res = getContext().getResources();
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new CardsWithHeadersDecoration(
                mAdapter, (int) res.getDimension(R.dimen.header_gap),
                (int) res.getDimension(R.dimen.row_gap)));
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
                new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    }

    mAdapter.updateData(inList);
    setWaitScreen(false);
}
```

I suspect, it stems from the initial layout loaded by the activity that somehow affects later fragments. Is this the case? If yes, how can I override the parent layout from the acquire fragment (so that it takes up the whole screen)?

Styles:

**layout/style/styles.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="UnityThemeSelector" parent="BaseUnityTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BaseUnityTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    </style>

    <style name="UnityThemeSelector.Translucent" parent="@style/UnityThemeSelector">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ToolBar -->
    <style name="ToolbarStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="titleTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <!-- CardView -->
    <style name="CardViewStyle" parent="CardView">
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/card_view_margin</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/card_view_margin</item>
        <item name="cardCornerRadius">@dimen/card_view_card_corner_radius</item>
        <item name="cardElevation">@dimen/card_view_card_elevation</item>
        <item name="cardPreventCornerOverlap">false</item>
    </style>

    <attr format="reference" name="cardViewStyle"/>
    <color name="cardview_dark_background">#FF424242</color>
    <color name="cardview_light_background">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="cardview_shadow_end_color">#03000000</color>
    <color name="cardview_shadow_start_color">#37000000</color>
    <declare-styleable name="CardView">
        <!-- Background color for CardView. -->
        <attr format="color" name="cardBackgroundColor"/>
        <!-- Corner radius for CardView. -->
        <attr format="dimension" name="cardCornerRadius"/>
        <!-- Elevation for CardView. -->
        <attr format="dimension" name="cardElevation"/>
        <!-- Maximum Elevation for CardView. -->
        <attr format="dimension" name="cardMaxElevation"/>
        <!-- Add padding in API v21+ as well to have the same measurements with previous versions. -->
        <attr format="boolean" name="cardUseCompatPadding"/>
        <!-- Add padding to CardView on v20 and before to prevent intersections between the Card content and rounded corners. -->
        <attr format="boolean" name="cardPreventCornerOverlap"/>
        <!-- Inner padding between the edges of the Card and children of the CardView. -->
        <attr format="dimension" name="contentPadding"/>
        <!-- Inner padding between the left edge of the Card and children of the CardView. -->
        <attr format="dimension" name="contentPaddingLeft"/>
        <!-- Inner padding between the right edge of the Card and children of the CardView. -->
        <attr format="dimension" name="contentPaddingRight"/>
        <!-- Inner padding between the top edge of the Card and children of the CardView. -->
        <attr format="dimension" name="contentPaddingTop"/>
        <!-- Inner padding between the bottom edge of the Card and children of the CardView. -->
        <attr format="dimension" name="contentPaddingBottom"/>
        <!-- Workaround to read user defined minimum width -->
        <attr name="android:minWidth"/>
        <!-- Workaround to read user defined minimum height -->
        <attr name="android:minHeight"/>
    </declare-styleable>
    <dimen name="cardview_compat_inset_shadow">1dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="cardview_default_elevation">2dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="cardview_default_radius">2dp</dimen>
    <style name="Base.CardView" parent="android:Widget">
        <item name="cardCornerRadius">@dimen/cardview_default_radius</item>
        <item name="cardElevation">@dimen/cardview_default_elevation</item>
        <item name="cardMaxElevation">@dimen/cardview_default_elevation</item>
        <item name="cardUseCompatPadding">false</item>
        <item name="cardPreventCornerOverlap">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="CardView" parent="Base.CardView">
    </style>
    <style name="CardView.Dark">
        <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/cardview_dark_background</item>
    </style>
    <style name="CardView.Light">
        <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/cardview_light_background</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/ascent_color</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_color_dark</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Button styles -->
    <style name="BaseButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
        <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/button_width</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/button_height</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ButtonStyle" parent="BaseButtonStyle">
        <item name="android:background">@color/ascent_color</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">bottom|end</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DriveButtonStyle" parent="ButtonStyle">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/ascent_color</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Why don't you copy the code it from there where it's working fine ? Or you want to show it as a dialog fit to screen in width only ?

Comment: I did, but I have to use a different activity layout (I have to use a PreferenceActivity instead of a FragmentActivity (due to billing constraints)). Yes, the fragment should take up the whole screen (both in terms of height and width) when viewed.

Comment: Apparently you are not developing it right. I have copied your code in my studio and it's messing up the layout. Let check and get back to you.

Comment: I have checked the code you have to develop it right your code doesn't corresponds to the requirement you have.

Comment: your cardview has no 'android:layout_width`

Comment: @Umair. Can you elaborate? The app (code snippet) is an expansion of the sample.

Comment: @Traendy Added styles to question.